# Pattern Matching in Python getting Error : called match pattern must be a type

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I have defined the following classes:

```
@dataclass
class Var:
    name: str


@dataclass
class Val:
    value: int


@dataclass
class Op:
    operation: str
    left: 'Node'
    right: 'Node'
```

and created a union type of these 3

```
Node = Var | Val | Op
```

Now I want to check using structural pattern matching the following cases:

```
match node:
    case Var(x):
        return x
    case Val(i):
        return str(i)
    case Op(operation, (left), (right)):
        return "(" + node_to_str(left) + " " + operation + " " + node_to_str(right) + ")"
```

The problem is, that, in the last case, left and right could be None, giving me an error. Hence, I would like to put the constraint on left and right that they must be a Node type:

```
    case Op(operation, Node(left), Node(right)):
        return "(" + node_to_str(left) + " " + operation + " " + node_to_str(right) + ")"
```

However, using this approach, I get the error: called match pattern must be a type.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

### Core issue

Type hints and class patterns are two different things.  Writing `Node = Var | Val | Op` creates a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-type-hint) usable for type annotations but not for class patterns:

```
>>> type(Node)
<class 'types.UnionType'>
```

### Easy solution

Create an upstream case to handle operands that are `None`.  Then when the three-way case is encountered, the inputs are known to be non-null:

```
match node:
    case Var(x):
        return x
    case Val(i):
        return str(i)
    case Op(operation, None, None):
        return "Empty operation"
    case Op(operation, left, right):
        return "Non-empty operation"
```

### Wordy solution

Instead of using the *Node* variable, just spell-out the [OR-pattern](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#combining-multiple-patterns-or-patterns):

```
match node:
    case Var(x):
        return x
    case Val(i):
        return str(i)
    case Op(operation, Var() | Val() | Op(), Var() | Val() | Op()):
        return "Non-empty operation"
```