# Pattern matching to check a protocol. Getting TypeError: called match pattern must be a type

Tags: python, typeerror, iterable, abc, structural-pattern-matching

I need to match cases where the input is [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable).  Here's what I tried:

```
from typing import Iterable

def detector(x: Iterable | int | float | None) -> bool:
    match x:
        case Iterable():
            print('Iterable')
            return True
        case _:
            print('Non iterable')
            return False
```

That is producing this error:

```
TypeError: called match pattern must be a type
```

Is it possible to detect iterability with match/case?

Note, these two questions address the same error message but neither question is about how to detect iterability:

- [how to fix TypeError: called match pattern must be a type in Python 3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918623/how-to-fix-typeerror-called-match-pattern-must-be-a-type-in-python-3-10)
- [Pattern Matching in Python getting Error : called match pattern must be a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70235233/pattern-matching-in-python-getting-error-called-match-pattern-must-be-a-type)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the [typing.Iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Iterable) is only for [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-type-hint) and is not considered a "type" by structural pattern matching.  Instead, you need to use an [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class) for detecting iterability: [collections.abc.Iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable).

The solution is distinguish the two cases, marking one as being a type hint and the other as a class pattern for structural pattern matching:

```
def detector(x: typing.Iterable | int | float | None) -> bool:
    match x:
        case collections.abc.Iterable():
            print('Iterable')
            return True
        case _:
            print('Non iterable')
            return False
```

Also note that at the time of this writing *mypy* does not support the *match* statement.